# Slicebox in Firefox

Tags: firefox, 3d, transform, modernizr, css-transforms

I try to use [Slicebox](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/09/05/slicebox-3d-image-slider/), but I can't get it works. It works great in Chrome and in Opera I see a nice fallback - but in Firefox I get only gray box. I think the problem is in Modernizr csstransforms3d detection. I'm not sure if Modernizr should detects 3d transforms. Do anyone know what exactly cause this bahaviour?

Answer (score 0):

After reading the code I could find the the reason.

All styles are written with a `-webkit` prefix but the script checks for `Modernizr.csstransforms3d`.
So as firefox supports `csstransforms3d` it tries to apply the 3d transform styles however firefox ignores all styles prefixed with `-webkit`.

My current solution is to prefix all styles correctly:

```
(function($){

    if(Modernizr.csstransforms3d) { 
        var prefix = "";
        if($.browser.mozilla){
            prefix = "-moz-";
        }else if($.browser.msie){
            prefix = "-ms-";
        }else if($.browser.opera){
            prefix = "-o-";
        }else{
            return;
        }
    }

    // Replace -webkit- with the current browser prefix
    var postProcessStyles = function(styles){
        $.each(styles,function(k,v){
            styles[k.replace('-webkit-', prefix)] = typeof v === 'string' ? v.replace('-webkit-', prefix) : v;
            styles[k.replace('-webkit-', '')] = typeof v === 'string' ? v.replace('-webkit-', '') : v;
        });
    }

    // Inject style processor
    var orig = $.Slice3d.prototype._configureStyles;
    $.Slice3d.prototype._configureStyles = function(){
        var origReturn = orig.apply(this,arguments),
            _this = this;
        postProcessStyles(this.style);      
        $.each(this.sidesStyles, function(k){
            postProcessStyles(_this.sidesStyles[k]);
        })  
        $.each(this.animationStyles, function(k){
            postProcessStyles(_this.animationStyles[k]);
        })      
        return origReturn;
    }

}(jQuery));
```

Demo:
http://jsbin.com/onokut/1

Code:
http://jsbin.com/onokut/1/edit

Comment: Do not do this. This will break in Firefox and Opera, where they do not prefix their transforms anymore

Comment: Use `Modernizr.prefixed('transform')` inside of postProcessStyles instead. It will correctly tell you what style property to use. http://modernizr.com/docs/#prefixed

Comment: Thank @PaulIrish I tried `Modernizr.prefixed(k.replace('-webkit-', ''))` however this causes only strange effects. I added a line to remove the prefixes in my code. What do you think about that?

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't seem to be compatible - they acknowledge that:

> Please note that you can only see the cool 3d effect of Slicebox in a
>   browser that supports those CSS3 properties (currently Chrome and
>   Safari).